# Raising a number to the exponent and natural "loging" it.

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I've taken a course on complex variables and when dealing with complex numbers I've noticed that we can denote:

z^c (where z is a complex number denoted by z = a + bi such that 'a' and 'b' are real numbers) by e^(c * log(z))

where log(z) = ln(|z|) + i * arg(z) --> where |z| = sqrt((a)^2 + (b)^2) and arg(z) is the angle of z (essentially using the polar coordinates and radius of z).

My question is, in the traditional sense, for real numbers, we were taught that x = e^ln(x). However when dealing with complex numbers this is clearly not the case (as this would be x = e^(1 * log(x)), log(x) = ln|x| + i*arg(x)). I was wondering why this is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give an example where $z \not = e^{\log z}$?  There is an issue that the complex logarithm can be multi-valued since you can add multiples of $2\pi$ to $\arg(z)$, but that does not affect the value of $e^{\log z}$

Comment: Yes I actually was remembering it incorrectly. The actual issue I wanted to mention was that: log(z^c) != c*log(z) all the time. For example: Log(i^3) != 3 * Log(i) such that the argument for Log is from -pi < theta < pi.

Comment: though note that in your example $\text{Log}(i^3)= -\frac{\pi}{2}i$ while  $3\text{Log}(i)= \frac{3\pi}{2}i$ so the difference is a multiple of $2\pi i$